# Fraction class troubleshooting

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

As an assignment I am supposed to create a Rational class for fractions and overload various operators in order to manipulate the fractions. But I'm having a lot of trouble sorting out how to do this. Here's my code and the current error messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Thanks for the help. It still has two error message. 
A ton(14+) of instances of: undefined reference to 'Rational::Rational()'
2: When I'm overloading the << operator it says that num and den aren't defined. How do I tell it to get the num and den from the object it is supposed to be printing out?
Thanks!

header file

```
#ifndef Rational_H
#define Rational_H

#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Rational
{

    friend Rational operator+(const Rational& x1, const Rational& x2);
    friend Rational operator-(const Rational& x1, const Rational& x2);
    friend Rational operator*(const Rational& x1, const Rational& x2);

public:
    Rational(); //constructor
    void setFraction(int, int); //set fractional
    int getNum() const;
    int getDen() const;

    void RSimplify();
    void printFraction();
    friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &, const Rational & );
    friend istream &operator>>( istream &, Rational & );

private:
    int num;
    int den;
 };

#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include <iomanip>
#include "Rational.h"
using namespace std;


int Rational::getNum() const
{
    return num;
}

int Rational::getDen() const
{
    return den;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const ATJRational &ATJRational)
{
    return output << num << "/" << den;
Error: num and den are not declared in this scope
}
istream &operator>>( istream &input, ATJRational &ATJRational)
{
    char slash;
    return input >> ATJRational.num >> slash >> ATJRational.den;
    ATJRational.RSimplify();
}

void ATJRational::RSimplify()
{
    for(int i=2; i<14; i++)
    {
        while(den % i == 0)
        {
            if(num % i == 0)
            {
                den = den / i;
                num = num / i;
            }
        }
    }
}


Rational operator+(const Rational& x1, const Rational& x2)
   {
     Rational x3;     
     x3.num = (x1.num * x2.den) + (x2.num * x1.den);
     x3.den = (x1.den * x2.den);
     x3.RSimplify();
     return x3;
   }

Rational operator-(const Rational& x1, const Rational& x2)
   {
     Rational x3;      // result
     x3.num = (x1.num * x2.den) - (x2.num * x1.den);
     x3.den = (x1.den * x2.den);
     x3.RSimplify();
     return x3;
   }

Rational operator*(const Rational& x1, const Rational& x2)
   {
     Rational x3;      // result
     x3.num = (x1.num * x2.num);
     x3.den = (x1.den * x2.den);
     x3.RSimplify();
     return x3;
   }
```

main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rational.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Rational x1; //create object fraction
    Rational x2;
    Rational x3;

    cout<<"Enter a fraction in the form 1/4:"<<endl;
    cin>>x1;

    cout<<"Enter a 2nd fraction in the form 1/4:"<<endl;
    cin>>x2;

    cout<<"The two fractions in their lowest terms are: "<<x1<<" and "<<x2<<endl;

    cout<<"Adding the 1st and 2nd fractions together..."<<endl;
    x3 = x1 + x2;
    cout<<"The sum of the two fractions is:"<<x3<<endl;

    cout<<"Subtracting the 1st fraction from the 2nd fraction..."<<endl;
    x3 = x2 - x1;
    cout<<"The result is:"<<x3<<endl;

    cout<<"Multiplying the 1st fraction by the 2nd fraction..."<<endl;
    x3 = x1 * x2;
    cout<<"The product is:"<<x3<<endl;

}
```

Comment: And your question is....

Comment: When you are writing code, as soon as you get one error, *stop*. Do not proceed until you have fixed that error.

Comment: You are doing many things wrong. Some of these are listed in my answer.

Comment: @Beta At this point I'm so lost I don't know what I'm doing. And I don't know which are errors and which aren't, due to not really knowing what it's supposed to look like. And before you say it, I have tried looking online and such. But that only helps so much.

Comment: You should show all the errors.  It will never work until after the errors are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring any logic errors, I can see a few problems. There could well be more.

First, this

```
RSimplify.x3;
```

should be

```
x3.RSimplify();
```

Second, your arithmetic operator definitions don't match the friend declarations. You are missing a `const` for the RHS:

```
Rational operator+(const Rational& x1, Rational& x2) { .... }
```

needs to be

```
Rational operator+(const Rational& x1, const Rational& x2) { .... }
```

Third, the output stream operator should act on the stream you pass it, not explicitly `cout`. So,

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Rational &Rational)
{
    return output << num << "/" << den;
}
```

Note it is also wise to leave it to the caller to add an `endl` or anything else.

Comment: I changed those. Thanks very much.